# passing custom object after serialization to WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest

I have a WCF service method with following signature:

```
  public string CTNotification(JSONRecordingCompletedNotification content)
        {
```

I want to create a client and consume it. I have written following code but it gives error:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/json.txt")))
                {
                    string serviceBaseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serviceurl"].ToString() + "CTNotification";
                    string conversationId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conversationId"].ToString();

                    String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    string jsonText = line;
                    string body = jsonText;

                JSONRecordingCompletedNotification RecordingCompletedNotification = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<JSONRecordingCompletedNotification>(body);

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceBaseUrl);
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/json";                   



                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    writer.Write(RecordingCompletedNotification);
                }

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                Label1.Text = response.ToString();
            }
```

I get following error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

Comment: You need to use enable tracing to see what's really going on under the hood. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: am I doing it correctly though ?

Comment: I think so... but I always think I'm doing it correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to use either of the lib for json serialization and deserialization

1. [json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)
2. [fastjson](http://fastjson.codeplex.com/)

and change the content type as

```
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
```